# How to select peak amount dates from table with date and amount columns

Tags: mysql, sql, date-range

I have a table with 2 columns, date and amount.  I want to be able to find x day peaks in amount.  So if I have the following table and am looking for say 3 day peaks, meaning amount is higher that day than any day for 3 days before or after then that date will be selected.

```
date         amount
2012-09-04 | 53137.47
2012-09-05 | 53137.2
2012-09-06 | 53137.54
2012-09-07 | 53138.58
2012-09-10 | 53138.73
2012-09-11 | 53138.28
2012-09-12 | 53138.22
2012-09-13 | 53138.48
2012-09-14 | 53140.14
2012-09-17 | 53139.82
2012-09-18 | 53139.86
2012-09-19 | 53140.01
2012-09-20 | 53139.75
2012-09-21 | 53139.82
2012-09-24 | 53139.01
2012-09-25 | 53138.93
2012-09-26 | 53138.48
2012-09-27 | 53138.83
2012-09-28 | 53138.62
```

Should select 2012-09-10, 2012-09-14

I have tried using joins and derived tables but I cannot seem to get it to work.

tried the following:

```
    select * from a WHERE  
amount=(select MAX(amount) from a where 
date<date_add(date,interval 3 day) and 
date>date_sub(date,interval 3 day));
```

and

```
    SELECT a1.*
    FROM a AS a1
    JOIN a AS a2 ON 
(select * from a1 where 
a2.DATE < a1.DATE + 3 and 
a2.DATE > a1.DATE - 3) myalias
    WHERE a1.amount > a2.amount;
```

Comment: Is the maximum to be calculated in an interval of +/- 3 calendar days (as indicated by your query attempts), or in an interval of +/- 3 consecutive dates in the table (as indicated by excluding 2012-09-19 from your desired result)?

Comment: I meant to calculate based on consecutive dates in the table, which I see now I was not doing.

Answer (score 0):

In order to find the maximum in a date interval, you have to join the record for the center date to the records for the other dates in the interval, and then group by the center date.

Try this query:

```
SELECT a1.date, a1.amount, max(a2.amount) AS highest
FROM tbl a1 LEFT JOIN tbl a2
ON a2.date BETWEEN date_sub(a1.date, interval 3 DAY)
           AND date_add(a1.date, interval 3 DAY)
GROUP BY a1.date, a1.amount
HAVING a1.amount = highest
ORDER BY a1.date;
```

To get an answer based on consecutive records instead of calendar days, you will have to augument the table with row numbers (by doing a self join of the table to itself), and then doing a self join of this extended table to itself selecting the rows within +/- 3 rows of each date when comparing the amounts:

```
SELECT t3.date FROM
  (SELECT t1.date AS date, t1.amount AS amount, count(t2.date) AS rownum
   FROM tbl t1
   INNER JOIN tbl t2
   ON t2.date <= t1.date
   GROUP BY t1.date, t1.amount) AS t3
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT t1.date AS date, t1.amount AS amount, count(t2.date) AS rownum
   FROM tbl t1
   INNER JOIN tbl t2
   ON t2.date <= t1.date
   GROUP BY t1.date, t1.amount) AS t4
ON t3.rownum <> t4.rownum
AND t3.rownum - t4.rownum  BETWEEN -3 AND 3
AND t4.amount >= t3.amount
WHERE t4.date IS NULL
ORDER BY t3.date
```

This works in both MySQL and PostgreSQL, and should work in other database engines as well.
In other databases than MySQL it can be simplified by using a CTE for the two subqueries.

Se this [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7823e/9/0) to test it.

Comment: Awesome!  That works perfectly for calendar days.  I will need to try and adjust for consecutive dates in the table as noted above.  Thanks!

Comment: Oops. I asked for a clarification, and then I misread the answer.

Comment: Thanks again.  I am using MySQL so, as you stated, I will need to find a different way.  I get the following error in MySQL when I try your example:  ERROR 1235 (42000): This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Comment: Check the updated answer for a query that works in MySQL as well.

Comment: Yes, the updated answer works great in MySQL.  I would have never figured this out.  It is way beyond my novice skills.  I bow down to your superior intellect. Thanks!